# Heroku web app not exporting NODE_ENV properly

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm running two instances with a Heroku app, a worker and a web app.

The worker is correctly showing its NODE_ENV var as `staging`, but the web app somehow is showing its NODE_ENV as `production`.

How can I troubleshoot this? When I run bash for that app, and echo the $NODE_ENV var, it shows up as `staging` correctly, but in logging software I'm using the `NODE_ENV` is showing up as a different value between the worker and the web app.

Comment: On the Heroku website you can go to `/settings` on your app and check the **Config Vars** that are set to a particular app.

Comment: Yup, have already done that of course. As you can see, one of my dynos correctly exports it, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have code in your Web app that is inadvertently setting process.env.NODE_ENV to production? 
For example, you might have something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV='production'){
}
```

If you have code like that somewhere in your Web app, it would be inadvertently setting NODE_ENV to "production".
If that is the case, you probably intended to write something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` set to `true`, and my script was being run during the `config` setup, so at that point the environment variable was still exported as `production`.

Changed `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` back to `false` and things are working OK again.